# Is it possible to change a for loop header within an if statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I believe the question is better understood with an example, say I have a for loop and I want to change whether it iterates over a dict or in a range of values depending on a variable. For **example**:

```
    my_dict = [ 'value_a':5, 'value_b':8, ... ]

    if some_boolean:
        for i in range(0, 10):
    else:
        for i in my_dict:

            # body of the for loop
```

This will not work since there is nothing under the first for statement. I've thought of making a dictionary with the values of the range() or writting the body of the loop twice, but I wonder if there is a more elegant solution.

**Is there any way of doing this without doing weird things with the variables?**

Thanks!

Comment: do you want to do that dynamically? or just at the start of the loop? is the variable able to change within the loop and change the iterable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this (for an alternative approach to the preceding answer.):

```
def loop(condition):
    iterable = range(0,10) if condition else ['a','b','c']
    return iterable

#Then you cxan go as:

for i in loop(True):
    print('range')
#Or

for i in loop(False):
    print("Dict or any iterable")
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know if statements could be used like that, now I can do
    for i in dictionary if condition else range(begin, end):
    ....

Thank you very much for your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

```
x = False #True

y = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,

z = 11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99

for i in y if x else z:
    print(i)
```

Should be fairly easy to understand, hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, a combination of both is the key to solve my problem :)